# Django-Rest Framework: Override determine_metadata() method

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

Following Django-Rest-Framework Doc about [Custom metadata](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/#custom-metadata-classes) I need to add an attribute (myatt) to determine_metadata() method, like this for example:

```
def determine_metadata(self, request, view):
        metadata = OrderedDict()
        metadata['name'] = view.get_view_name()
        metadata['description'] = view.get_view_description()
        metadata['myatt'] = 'blablabla'
        metadata['renders'] = [renderer.media_type for renderer in view.renderer_classes]
        metadata['parses'] = [parser.media_type for parser in view.parser_classes]
        if hasattr(view, 'get_serializer'):
            actions = self.determine_actions(request, view)
            if actions:
                metadata['actions'] = actions
        return metadata
```

I edited the metadata.py file in rest-framework directory just to test it and worked. However in the correct way, I know that I shall override the determine_metadata() method to accomplish what I want.
My problem is that I don't know **where** and **how** shall I override it.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

**You can create a `MyCustomMetadata` class which will add an extra attribute to the metadata.**

This class will inherit from `SimpleMetadata` class which is the default metadata class in DRF. Then, we will override the `determine_metadata()` function in it. We first call the super() to get the original `metadata` returned by DRF, then we add our extra attribute to the `metadata`.

**my_app/metadata.py**

```
from rest_framework.metadata import SimpleMetadata

class MyCustomMetadata(SimpleMetadata):

    def determine_metadata(self, request, view):
        metadata = super(MyCustomMetadata, self).determine_metadata(request, view)
        metadata['myatt'] = 'blablabla' # add extra attribute to metadata
        return metadata # return the metadata with the extra attribute set in it
```

Now, we need to define `MyCustomMetadata` class in our settings which will be used by DRF then.

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': 'my_app.metadata.MyCustomMetadata'
}
```